# Double summation and iterated summation

Tags: real-analysis

For $X$ and $Y$ are two finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and a function $f(x,y): \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$.

We will have the result:

> $\sum \limits_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} f(x,y)$ = $\sum \limits_{x \in X} \sum \limits_{y \in Y} f(x,y)$

1. Could you please explain me the difference between the $LHS$ and the $RHS$ expression. In more details, I don't really understand how we perform the calculation procedure of $\sum \limits_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} f(x,y)$, it is quite un-intuitive for me.
2. Could you please show me the rigorous definition of double summation $\sum \sum$ (or more general, the expression with $n$ number of $\sum$ notations).

Note: For the $RHS$ summation, I understand clearly that we keep $x$ fixed, then calculate the sum of function of variable $y$ to get a function $g(x)$ = $\sum \limits_{y \in Y} f(x,y)$, then we calculate the sum of the function of variable $x$ which is $\sum \limits_{x \in X} g(x)$)

Thank you very much!

Comment: $\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)$ is the result of summing over the uncountable set $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the mappings $f(x,y)\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.  Unless for every $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there are only finitely many $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y)(u,v)$ is nonzero, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user10354138: Hi. Thanks for your comment. There is a typo in my question. The summation should be written $\sum \limits_{(x,y) \in X \times Y}$. Could you have a look again at it ? Moreover, could you please tell me the technical difference between the summation over the set $X \times Y$ and the iterated summation ? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It is just a finite sum.  You can sum in any order you like in the LHS, not necessarily grouping those with the same $x$ together as in RHS.

Comment: @user10354138: And in practice, it is easier to calculate with the process of the RHS, so that is the reason why we need this relationship ? ($i.e$ the equation of the LHS and the RHS)

Comment: Why is it easier to calculate with RHS?  Why can't you, for example, group the same $y$ first?  Or go in a "spiral"?

Comment: @user10354138: yes, I mean I think that the iterated summation will be easier ($i.e.$ keep $x$ or $y$ fixed first) than summation in the arbitrary order in the $X \times Y$ set

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example, summing over four corners of a square where opposite sum to $0$, or summing from the least to the greatest (important for floating point arithmetics on computers).

Comment: @user10354138: You are right, but I think in most case that will be easier, especially when we are dealing with integration in $\mathbb{R^n}$, it is easier to do it with the iterated integration I think.